# puppeteer / chromium: generating pdf different div heights

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer, chromium

we're generating a pdf in a node backend like this:

```
const pdf = await page.pdf({
    format: 'A4',
    printBackground: true,
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
  });
```

problem is that we are dynamically calculating, with javascript the height of every paragraph do decide when to put a page break, like this:

```
const totalHeight = $(el).outerHeight(true)
```

but in some conditions the height is different between client generation and local (on the server is a linux, locally is a mac). On the linux the height is wrong.

as you can see in the following screenshot, a paragraph that is also visually on a single line, is calculated as a double line (36 instead of 18):

[image]

here it is the correct size calculated on a local machine:
[image]

any ideas why this happens will be appreciated.

Comment: are the fonts the same?

Comment: @WillJenkins yes of course, moreover as you can see in the first screenshot, the same line, cut shorter, will have an height of 18, while the first 36